# Color every Nth line in a SVG group

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to use css to color a series of lines in a svg group, with every 5th line to be a different color. What I have correctly colours the 5th line, but doesn't for the following 10th, 15th, ect.

```css
 .grid {
  stroke: cyan;
 }
 .grid:nth-of-type(5) {
  stroke: magenta;
 }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="600">
<g class="gridContainer">
  <line x1="18" y1="0" x2="18" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="36" y1="0" x2="36" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="54" y1="0" x2="54" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="72" y1="0" x2="72" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="90" y1="0" x2="90" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="108" y1="0" x2="108" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="126" y1="0" x2="126" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="144" y1="0" x2="144" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="162" y1="0" x2="162" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="180" y1="0" x2="180" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="198" y1="0" x2="198" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="216" y1="0" x2="216" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="234" y1="0" x2="234" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="252" y1="0" x2="252" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="270" y1="0" x2="270" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="288" y1="0" x2="288" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="306" y1="0" x2="306" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: The answer by @johannchopin is correct, but before asking you have to do more research... For example you can find on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) the explanation for nth-child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `.grid:nth-of-type(5n)`

```css
.grid {
  stroke: cyan;
}
.grid:nth-of-type(5n) {
  stroke: magenta;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="600">
<g class="gridContainer">
  <line x1="18" y1="0" x2="18" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="36" y1="0" x2="36" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="54" y1="0" x2="54" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="72" y1="0" x2="72" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="90" y1="0" x2="90" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="108" y1="0" x2="108" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="126" y1="0" x2="126" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="144" y1="0" x2="144" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="162" y1="0" x2="162" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="180" y1="0" x2="180" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="198" y1="0" x2="198" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="216" y1="0" x2="216" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="234" y1="0" x2="234" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="252" y1="0" x2="252" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="270" y1="0" x2="270" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="288" y1="0" x2="288" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
  <line x1="306" y1="0" x2="306" y2="600" stroke-width="2" class="grid"></line>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is correct, but a short blurb of explanation and/or link to the relevant spec would be good.